# How can we sort manga (by genre) within Crunchyroll's manga utility or mobile app?

Tags: resources, crunchyroll

I've been considering getting a Crunchyroll membership primarily for the manga rather than the anime. Looking on their site, Crunchyroll does not have anyway to organize and parse through their manga library other than alphabetically. They do not have a way to search by genre or anything like that.

Is the mobile app for Android any better? Does it have sorting?

Comment: Before anyone has an impulse to close this, [this relevant Meta answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/916/1020) explains why this should *definitely* be on-topic.  Well, at least *parts* of this question, anyway.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the parts that would make future answers to this more based in opinion rather than fact.

Comment: @Makoto Alright, thanks. I was originally going to ask a different question, and changed my mind halfway through. I didn't do a good enough job editing it down before I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Crunchyroll Manga app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crunchyroll.crmanga), you have the ability to sort...

[image]

...and sort by a specific genre you're looking for.

[image]

The kicker here is that the genres *you* may be thinking of *might not* be the same ones that Crunchyroll supports.

[image]

Comment: Are all of the titles free if you have a membership (in North America, since I see that you are from the states)? It seems like in the UK (or at least Europe) that you have to pay for series individually on top of having a premium membership. (@peionrayz's answer)

Comment: I can't realistically answer that for you; you would be better served posing that specific question to Crunchyroll's support team.  I can answer your question insofar as to how the app works and what it's capable of doing.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I had assumed that you had a membership, apologies.

Comment: I do, but this is the fine line we walk here.  We can't say much about the support of the product, and given that I live in a different part of the world than you, I'd be ill equipped to talk about these features.  Your best bet and best shot to get some insight into this would be to genuinely contact Crunchyroll.

Answer (score 1):

On the Android mobile app there looks to be two main filters *featured* and *newest*, other than that you can search for manga in their manga store. This allowed me to find what looks like all the Attack on Titan manga. It looks like it also has most of the Fairy Tail manga too. (I don't want to check all 50+ books) It however doesn't have One Piece, Naruto, or Bleach in their store.

Even though I have Crunchyroll prime all the manga, seem to, have to be bought. The majority of Attack on Titan is selling for $10.99, which also isn't localized to the GBP on my app.

Comment: Do you know if the fact that you have to purchase manga individually is something restricted to the UK/Europe, or includes North America too? I'm in Canada.